# ReactJS async axios in Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I get data from a rest-api in `context.js`. And I assign the data to state. Here is the code from  `context.js`:

```
export class AppProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        products: [],
        cart: [],
        dispatch: action => this.setState(state => reducer(state, action))
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        const products = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:4000/product/all', { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" } })
        this.setState({
            products: products.data
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AppContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm using the data in the state in other components. But when the page is refreshed, i'm not using the data in the state in other components. When the page is refreshed, the state in `context.js` becomes the initial. how can i solve this problem? Here is the code from other component:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Badge } from 'reactstrap';
import './ProductDetail.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faShoppingCart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { AppContext } from '../../../context/context';
import { toast, Slide } from 'react-toastify';
toast.configure();
const ProductDetail = props => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(1);


    const preventNegative = e => {
        const value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '');
        if (parseInt(value) !== 0) {
            setInputValue(value);
        }
    }

    const addToCart = (e, productID) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
        const product = products.filter(p => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
            if (p.id == productID) {
                return p
            }
        })
        console.log(product);
        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
            payload: [product, inputValue]
        })
        toast.success("The product has been added to cart successfully !", {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
            autoClose: 2500,
            transition: Slide
        })
    }



    const { products, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext)
    const filteredProduct = products.filter(p => p.id == props.match.params.id)

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <main className="mt-5 pt-4">
                <div className="container dark-grey-text mt-5">
                    <div className="row wow fadeIn">
                        <div className="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <img src={filteredProduct[0].image} className="img-fluid" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <div className="p-4">
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <Badge color="primary">New</Badge>
                                    <Badge color="success">Best seller</Badge>
                                    <Badge color="danger">{filteredProduct[0].discountRate}% OFF</Badge>
                                </div>
                                <h2 className="h2">{filteredProduct[0].title}</h2>
                                <p className="lead">
                                    <span className="mr-1">
                                        <del>${filteredProduct[0].prevPrice}</del>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>${filteredProduct[0].price}</span>
                                </p>
                                <p className="text-muted">
                                    {filteredProduct[0].detail}
                                </p>
                                <form className="d-flex justify-content-left">
                                    <input
                                        min="1"
                                        onChange={(e) => preventNegative(e)}
                                        value={inputValue}
                                        type="number"
                                        aria-label="Search"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        style={{ width: '100px' }} />

                                    <Button onClick={(e) => addToCart(e, filteredProduct[0].id)} color="primary">Add to Cart <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingCart} /> </Button>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>

    )
}
export default ProductDetail;
```

Comment: Is your get request resolving correctly? If you log `products` before you set the state does it look correct?

Comment: waht is the expected behavior on page refresh ?? save data in localstorage and init from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AppProvider` component is correct, the only problem you have is because you fetch the results from an API and you do that in `componentDidMount` which is supposed to be the correct.

However when you refresh the page the set in `AppProvider` is reset to initial value and as you are already on `ProductDetail` component, you try to access the product values even before it available from the API request and hence

```
const filteredProduct = products.filter(p => p.id == props.match.params.id)
```

will return you can empty array.

The problem occurs because you try to access `filteredProduct[0].image` and similar other properties.

The solution here is to use a loadingState and render a loader till the data is available

Also do make sure that when the data is available `filteredProduct` will never be empty

```
export class AppProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        products: [],
        cart: [],
        dispatch: action => this.setState(state => reducer(state, action))
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        const products = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:4000/product/all', { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" } })
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            products: products.data
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AppContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

and in productDetails

```
const ProductDetail = props => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(1);


    const preventNegative = e => {
        const value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '');
        if (parseInt(value) !== 0) {
            setInputValue(value);
        }
    }

    const addToCart = (e, productID) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
        const product = products.filter(p => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
            if (p.id == productID) {
                return p
            }
        })
        console.log(product);
        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
            payload: [product, inputValue]
        })
        toast.success("The product has been added to cart successfully !", {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
            autoClose: 2500,
            transition: Slide
        })
    }



    const { products, dispatch, isLoading } = useContext(AppContext)
    if(isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

    const filteredProduct = products.filter(p => p.id == props.match.params.id)

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <main className="mt-5 pt-4">
                <div className="container dark-grey-text mt-5">
                    <div className="row wow fadeIn">
                        <div className="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <img src={filteredProduct[0].image} className="img-fluid" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <div className="p-4">
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <Badge color="primary">New</Badge>
                                    <Badge color="success">Best seller</Badge>
                                    <Badge color="danger">{filteredProduct[0].discountRate}% OFF</Badge>
                                </div>
                                <h2 className="h2">{filteredProduct[0].title}</h2>
                                <p className="lead">
                                    <span className="mr-1">
                                        <del>${filteredProduct[0].prevPrice}</del>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>${filteredProduct[0].price}</span>
                                </p>
                                <p className="text-muted">
                                    {filteredProduct[0].detail}
                                </p>
                                <form className="d-flex justify-content-left">
                                    <input
                                        min="1"
                                        onChange={(e) => preventNegative(e)}
                                        value={inputValue}
                                        type="number"
                                        aria-label="Search"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        style={{ width: '100px' }} />

                                    <Button onClick={(e) => addToCart(e, filteredProduct[0].id)} color="primary">Add to Cart <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingCart} /> </Button>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>

    )
}
export default ProductDetail;
```